# makeMKV setup error

Tags: software-installation, gcc

When I run `sudo bash configure` (`./configure` doesn't work), I get this:

> checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in
>   `/media/pitaj/Shared/Documents/makeMKV/makemkv-oss': configure: error:
>   cannot run C compiled programs. If you meant to cross compile, use`
>   --host'. See `config.log' for more details

In console.log, it says that `gcc -V` isn't valid

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the folder you are compiling on is mounted with the `noexec` option. 
For security reasons, `tmpfs` under `/tmp` is mounted `noexec`.

Move the entire folder to a mount that can execute programs or remount the place with different options. Background: The configure script needs to perform some basic tests which also involve compiling and running the compiled test program.

Comment: You were right. I had the files on an NTFS partition. Moved them to my main partition, and it worked like a charm.